# Python - how to access nested dictionary items from REST call

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I want to access a nested dictionary item from a REST call but I can't figure out how to access it.

Here is the response:

```
{"deck_id": "z4p8ee99e7wu", "success": true, "cards": [{"suit": "DIAMONDS", "code": "6D", "value": "6", "images": {"png": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/6D.png", "svg": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/6D.svg"}, "image": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/6D.png"}], "remaining": 51}
```

(I am really interested in the image link)
This is a public REST API, so anyone could run this code.
My goal is to eventually create a card game, but as you can see, I am just a beginner.)

Here is the code:

```
import requests
import json

response = 
requests.get('https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/shuffle/? 
deck_count=1')

print(response.text)
print(" ")
print("Status code: " + str(response.status_code))
print("Content type: " + response.headers['content-type']) 
data = response.json()

print("deck ID: %s" % data["deck_id"])
print("remaining: %s" % data["remaining"])

deckid=data["deck_id"]
remaining=data["remaining"]

card_var = 
requests.get('https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/'+deckid+'/draw/? 
count=1')
print(card_var.text)
carddata = card_var.json()
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access card image with :

```
carddata['cards'][0]['image']
```

Answer (score 1):

what about `carddata['cards'][0]['images']`?

More specifically, `carddata['cards'][0]['images']['svg']`, and
`carddata['cards'][0]['images']['png']` will return individual formats, `svg` and `png` links.

Answer (score 0):

```
for card in data['cards']:
    print 'card code is %s' % card['code']
    for ext in card['images']:
        print '%s image url is %s' % (ext, card['images'][ext])
```